# Pourquoi « faire » ne s'accorde-t-il pas normalement au passé composé ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, participe-passé, auxiliaires

On ne dit pas

> *Marie s'est faite diagonaliser

mais

> Marie s'est fait diagonaliser

Alors qu'on dirait

> Marie s'est sentie diagonaliser

et non

> *Marie s'est senti diagonaliser

Ceci est-il particulier à *faire* ? Et, si oui, d'où vient cette étrangeté ?

**Note** Le lecteur perturbé par *diagonaliser* pourra à peu de frais le remplacer par *manger*, les nourritures spirituelles et terrestres étant commutatives.

Comment: diagonaliser? private joke?

Comment: Sans la moindre idée du sens de 'diagonaliser', c'est assez dur de répondre, mais il me semblerait que les deux derniers exemples devraient prendre un participe, non? "senti(e) diagonalisée"...

Comment: S'il y a une règle, elle n'est pas liée à *faire* mais au fait que le verbe est pronominal.

Comment: Pour ceux qui ne savons pas ce que _diagonaliser_ veut dire, voir le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diagonaliser)…

Comment: Bon, essayons [Wikipédia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Diagonalisation) alors :)

Comment: Euh, je sais bien (fort hélas) ce que veut dire 'diagonaliser', en mathématiques. Mais à moins que 'Marie' ne soit le nom d'une matrice ayant développé une conscience, j'ai toujours du mal à voir ce que peuvent vouloir dire les exemples ci-dessus.

Comment: @Dave: [Rien](http://formes-symboliques.org/article.php3?id_article=193) ? Il faut que ça veuille dire quelque chose ? Et puis si j'ai envie de donner des petits noms à mes matrices, hein. Bon, je suis de mauvaise foi. Imagine par exemple que Marie est étudiante en mathématique et que la réduction des endomorphismes la perturbe au point qu'elle en devienne somnambule et les diagonalise pendant son sommeil.

Comment: @Evpok: blague à part, je pense que ça peut aider que l'exemple ait un sens (comme le montrent les remarques ci-dessus). Et même avec ton explication, "Marie s'est faite diagonaliser" ressemble plus à un acte sexuel bizarre qu'à un terme mathématique.

Comment: @Dave:  d'autant plus  que la possibilté de se faire diagonaliser dépend du corps sur lequel on est...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cette situation est particulière à *faire*. Cependant, les Rectifications tracent un parallèle entre *faire* et *laisser* et recommandent l'invariabilité du participe passé lorsque *laisser* est suivi d'un infinitif. Il faut bien noter que l'invariabilité ne s'applique que lorsque *faire*, ou *laisser*, est suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif.

Voici les explications du logiciel Antidote HD (version 5.1) au sujet de *faire* :

> Lorsqu’il est immédiatement suivi d’un infinitif, le participe passé *fait* est toujours invariable puisque le **complément direct** placé devant le verbe ne pourra jamais être interprété comme le complément du participe passé.
>
> **Avec l’auxiliaire *avoir***
>   Nous ***avons fait*** manger fiston avant notre départ.
>   Les filles que ces paroles ***ont fait*** pleurer ne reviendront probablement pas.
>   Avant qu’ils n’aient eu le temps de réfléchir, Marine leur ***avait fait*** signer le contrat.
>
> **Avec l’auxiliaire *être***
>   Didier et Raphaël ***se sont fait*** payer un verre.
>   La toiture qu’elle ***s’est fait*** construire durera cinq ans.
>   La maison qu’ils ***se sont fait*** construire est située sur les bords de la Meuse.

Et de *laisser* :

> Considérant que le rôle de *laisser* devant un infinitif est similaire à celui de ***faire***, les **rectifications de l’orthographe** recommandent que le participe passé de laisser soit désormais toujours invariable dans ce contexte, quelle que soit la position de l’**objet direct**, et que ce dernier soit ou non le sujet sous-entendu de l’infinitif qui suit.
>
> Le propriétaire nous a ***laissé*** prendre des photos de sa somptueuse demeure.
>   La lionne, gravement blessée, s’est ***laissé*** mourir.